# Eslint Minor change causes 10x speed decrease

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint, eslintrc

I don't understand. Changing the first eslint config to the config below made it 10x slower. I tried some debugging and printed all the files that were traversed/linted by both and they were identical. I also checked in vscode and tried to violate some of the rules in random parts of the app and it was caught with both configs so I don't understand how the second one can be so slow.

```
extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:vue/vue3-strongly-recommended',
    'plugin:vuejs-accessibility/recommended'
],
plugins: ['import'],
parser: 'vue-eslint-parser',
parserOptions: {
    parser: {
        js: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
        ts: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
},
```

Updated Config

```
extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:vue/vue3-strongly-recommended',
    'plugin:vuejs-accessibility/recommended'
],
plugins: ['import'],
parser: 'vue-eslint-parser',
parserOptions: {
    'parser': '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
    project: './tsconfig.eslint.json',
    sourceType: 'module',
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    'extraFileExtensions': ['.vue']
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the tsconfig option is only required if you want to use rules which require type information. I believe it will make eslint use typescript to transpile before doing the type-checking. Hence the significant speed decrease. If you aren't using any of these rules it is best to not use the tsconfig option. Eslint also has an experimental option `useProjectServices`.

https://typescript-eslint.io/packages/parser/

```
   • @typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-type-assertion
   • @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises
   • @typescript-eslint/prefer-nullish-coalescing
   • @typescript-eslint/prefer-optional-chain
   • @typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises
   • @typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-boolean-literal-compare
   • @typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions
   • @typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition
   • @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
   • @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call
   • @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
   • @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return
   • @typescript-eslint/no-implied-eval
   • @typescript-eslint/no-throw-literal
   • @typescript-eslint/require-await
   • @typescript-eslint/unbound-method
```